# About Image click Issue

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I have a question about image click issue:

I am using parallax effect with sticky, in this my `Viewpager` is not working on clicking.
My requirement is if user clicks on that,then he should redirect to another page.I am using [this](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-listview-parallax-effect-with-a-sticky) link for that.

I am using Viewpager instead of Imageview and Viewpager has Some Image Sliding.
thats not Working.I am getting an Array Of Images.

Any idea where i am wrong ?

Thanks.

```
 My Code:
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 private TextView stickyView;
 private ListView listView;
 private View heroImageView;

 private View stickyViewSpacer;

 private int MAX_ROWS = 20;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* Initialise list view, hero image, and sticky view */
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    heroImageView = findViewById(R.id.heroImageView);
    stickyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stickyView);

    heroImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(CollectionDetailActivity.this, "click",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    /* Inflate list header layout */
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
    stickyViewSpacer = listHeader.findViewById(R.id.stickyViewPlaceholder);

    /* Add list view header */
    listView.addHeaderView(listHeader);

    /* Handle list View scroll events */
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)           {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            /* Check if the first item is already reached to top.*/
            if (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
                View firstChild = listView.getChildAt(0);
                int topY = 0;
                if (firstChild != null) {
                    topY = firstChild.getTop();
                }

                int heroTopY = stickyViewSpacer.getTop();
                stickyView.setY(Math.max(0, heroTopY + topY));

                /* Set the image to scroll half of the amount that of ListView */
                heroImageView.setY(topY * 0.5f);
            }
        }
    });


    /* Populate the ListView with sample data */
    List<String> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        modelList.add("List item " + i);
    }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, modelList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Did you add Click event on that Imageview?

Comment: Yes.I think its effect thats why its not clicking

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: @DivyangPatel Maybe [this](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) library will help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to view hierarchy, ListView on a ImageView and click event will be handle by ListView. StickyView on a ListView. If you need handle click event ImageView you can  use click event space item(list_header layout) of ListView.

Change your :

```
heroImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(CollectionDetailActivity.this, "click",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

code to this :

```
    stickyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "stickyView clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and add this to handle click event of ImageView :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "heroImageView clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //ListView item clicked
        }
     }
});
```

[Complete code](https://codeshare.io/i7vn5)

Comment: i am using Viewpager instead of Imageview then how can i manage this scenario?